# How to manipulate the column values in EF4.0 used by ria domain service

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4

```
IQueryable<vwCandList> vwt = from o in this.ObjectContext.vwCandLists 
                             where o.ID == ownerID 
                             select new vwCandList { 
                               noteID = o.noteID, 
                               DateMade = o.DateMade.Value.AddMinutes(600),
                               ownerID = o.ownerID, 
                               ownerType = o.ownerType, 
                               Type = o.Type };
```

it complies very well but when called from aspx page it is throwing error of "The entity or complex type 'RM.vwCandList' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."

Pls help.

Comment: @user505274...Welcome to SO. I believe I can help you but I need to see the following two models(classes) to help you vwCandidateNoteList, vwCandList

Comment: Is this a stored procedure your executing? If so you shouldn't be using IQueryable, you should be using `DataContext.ExecuteQuery<vwCandidateNoteList>()`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just select o? Naming wise they appear to be the same type and you can iterate over the result to add the 10 hours after it is fetched.

Comment: Could you please tell me the code snippet to know how i will iterate it and add hours in the datemade  field and return the result from the same method as IQueryable as on the front end i am using ajaxgrid for paging, sorting, etc

Comment: Ah, that changes things. I'm not too familiar with the AjaxGrid, does it bind directly to the IQueryable or is there a database in between?